# using values within if conditions in mark up

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, databinder

I want to use a value that is pulled from the SQL within the if statement. Ideally i want to do the equivalent of

```
<% If DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BookID") == 1 Then%>
```

Is there a way to do this with the correct syntax?

Comment: Explain what Eval(Container, "DataItem.BookID") is?

Comment: DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BookID") throws an error as Container is not declared. however the value of BookID is the value i need to compare to 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you put conditions in aspx file. Just a rough sample base on what I understand:

```
<%# System.Convert.ToInt32((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BookID")!="") ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BookID"):0) %>
```

Make sure you have int in BookID not any other type.

**Explaining Further:**

In case you want to have an if else condition:

```
<%# If DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DATAFIELD") <> "" Then

   Response.Write("something")

End If %> // This is invalid
```

The above statement can be **properly** written in aspx file as this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataField").Equals("")?"":"Something"%>
```

Comment: How can i get the value from that into an if statement?

Comment: This does not work for if bookid = 1 then use this Hyperlink
else use this hyperlink

Comment: <% If "ParentTypeID" = 1 Then%>

                     <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/Preview.gif" NavigateUrl="" ></asp:HyperLink>
                  
                  <% Else%>

                  <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/Preview.gif" NavigateUrl="" ></asp:HyperLink>

                  <%End If%>


that is what i want to do, it is getting the value of ParentTypeID that i am struggling with

Comment: both condition doing the same thing?

Comment: what would i put into the "something"? i dont understand how that works

Comment: You can get it like this: <% If <%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ParentTypeID")) == 1 Then%>, still pretty difficult to understand your logic.

Comment: instead of "something" you put *else* condition, whatever that is.

Comment: your comment with the if does not work there are too starting tags

Comment: try this: <% If Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ParentTypeID")) == 1 Then%>

Comment: that doesnt work with the same exception i was getting before

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be done or not the way you are requesting it.

As you may or may not know, the typical way to do this is to have a control in your markup, like so

```
<asp:listView ID="SophiesListView" ...
..
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlGlossary" title="click here for more information" target="_blank" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:listView />
```

Then, in the codebehind, find your listview / repeater / datagrid or what have you and choose ItemDataBound. Inside this event, do something like this:

```
If e.Item.DataItem("vehicleType") IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso e.Item.DataItem("vehicleType") = "JETSKI" Then
    DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("hlGlossary"), HyperLink).NavigateUrl = "Glossary.aspx#JETSKI"
    DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("hlGlossary"), HyperLink).Text = "?"
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

To keep your page logic as simple as possible your best bet is to data bind to the Visible property of controls. For example, if you want to only show some html if the BookID == 1 then create a new property on your data source like this

```
public bool Show
{
     get
     {
         return BookID == 1;
     }
}
```

and in your page you'd have

```
<asp:Placeholder runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Show") %>'>
    ...html goes here...
</asp:Placeholder>
```