# Is there a way to use a DataBinder.Eval statement as an index of a specific array in an ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, databinder

Is there a way to use a DataBinder.Eval statement as an index of a specific array in an ASPX page?

I'm trying to develop a page containing a list of bibliographic references, for which I'm using the ASP.NET 2.0 Repeater control.

I'm quite new to ASP.NET, so I've carefully read the various answers about [Formatting DataBinder.Eval data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275194/formatting-databinder-eval-data) and [using values within if conditions in mark up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117962/using-values-within-if-conditions-in-mark-up) which both deal with the usage of DataBinder.Eval statements, but I'm stuck with my array (which is called Refbib() )...

I tried this :

```
<%# RefBib(System.Convert.ToInt32((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")!="") ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id"):0))%>
```

for which I received an error message BC30203: Identifier expected

Could someone explain what is wrong in my syntax?

Comment: Why do you have the link to your question as title?

Comment: @PeeHaa Wasn't their question.

Comment: I just realized that I forgot the title while pressing send & then wanted to udpate it at the same time of J. Steen