# Databinder inside a "for" loop in an ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, databinder

I'm still trying to understand how I can take advantage from DataBinder ( [Is there a way to use a DataBinder.Eval statement as an index of a specific array in an ASPX page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006141/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-databinder-eval-statement-as-an-index-of-a-specific-arra) ).

I'm currently building tables with the help of repeater and I would like to use a loop defining the Item label dynamically, to allow more interactions.

Currently, this test code is working:

```
<asp:Repeater id="Fish" runat="server">
<table>
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td><%# Container.DataItem("ITEM")%></td>
    <td><%# Container.DataItem("AGG")%></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</table>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But as you can imagine, this type of structure doesn't allow to choose dynamically the columns that are displayed from the columns to be ignored.

I was thinking that by using a "for" loop structure, I would be able to choose dynamically which column could be displayed. And I tried this as a test:

```
Public Test_id() As String
Public Test_idp As String

<% Test_id = New String() {"id", "Agg"} %>
<asp:Repeater id="Fish" runat="server">
<table>
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <% For Each Test_idp as String In Test_id%>
      <td><%# Container.DataItem(Test_idp)%></td>
    <% Next Test_idp%>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</table>
</asp:Repeater>
```

which is not working... and is granted by the following error message:

> Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Item' is most specific for these arguments:
>
> 'Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Item(name As String) As System.Object': Not most specific.
>
> 'Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Item(i As Integer) As System.Object': Not most  specific.

Any idea?

---

Edit:

to answer Mike C's question, I have tried `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, Test_idp)` instead of `Container.DataItem(Test_idp)`. It still does not work, but the error is different:

> System.ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null

Comment: Instead of `Container.DataItem(Test_idp)` have you tried `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, Test_idp)`?

Comment: @MikeC I have just tried it - it doesn't work and the error is different. I've updated the description of my example

Answer (score 2):

`Test_Idp` is an `Object` (since it wasn't declared otherwise).

Therefore, the compiler cannot figure out which of those overloads to call.

You need to explicitly declare it `As String`.

Comment: I should have added that I have declared both Test_id and Test_idp as string:
    Public Test_id() As String and 
    Public Test_idp As String

Comment: @S3MP `Test_idp` is NOT declared as a string in your code example.  If you have changed it since then, then you need to update your example so that it says `For Each Test_idp As String...`.

Comment: @MikeC Ok sorry - example updated - tested - still the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested repeater for the columns.

```
<asp:Repeater id="Fish" runat="server">
<table>
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <asp:Repeater id="columns" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <td><%# ((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem("ITEM")%></td>
          <td><%# ((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem("AGG")%></td>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater> 
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</table>
</asp:Repeater>
```